# Tree traversal with page property sortIndex

Tags: python, google-app-engine, tree-traversal

I'm building a tree structure based on a list retrieved from a `db.Model` called Pages.

Each Page entry has a parentKey property that's a `db.SelfReferenceProperty()` and a `db.IntegerProperty()` called sortIndex.

I fetch the list and call a method to travers over the list and make a nestled dict as my tree. The reason I fetch the entire list is that I want to skip multiple queries.

```
pages = Pages.gql('ORDER BY sortIndex').fetch(1000)
build_tree(pages)
```

And the build_tree:

```
def build_tree(nodes, *args):
    # create empty tree to fill
    tree = {}
    build_tree_recursive(tree, None, nodes, *args)

    return tree

def build_tree_recursive(tree, parent, nodes, *args):
    # find root children, first level nodes have no parentKey
    if parent is None:
        children  = [n for n in nodes if n.parentKey == None]
    # find children
    else:
        children  = [n for n in nodes if n.parentKey is not None and n.parentKey.key() == parent]

    # build a subtree for each child
    for child in children:
        # start new subtree
        key = child.key()
        # Use page entry key as unique dict key
        tree[key] = { 'page' : child, 'children' : {}}
        # call recursively to build a subtree for current node
        build_tree_recursive(tree[key]['children'], key, nodes)
```

The problem is that the list get's rearranged and don't follow det ORDER BY. I think this is due to that each Page is put in the list when a proper parent is found. But even the first level (Pages that has `parentKey == None`) get's returned in the wrong order.

I've tried setting a prefix using a loop counter on tree[str(i) + '_' + str(key)] but still didn't return in a proper order.

So the question how to get them in an proper order?

**EDIT [Solved]:**

See below

Comment: Be aware that you're not saving on queries here - every time you do 'n.parentkey' for the first time on an entity, it fetches the entity from the datastore.

Comment: Thanks. I been working on this for the last couple of hours and indeed noticed it. Any ideas of how to get around it? I think I read somewhere that one can pre-catch some data?

Comment: @fredrik: if you had answered your own question instead of editing it (possible even marking it as accepted) others would not find your question again and again, when searching for old, unanswered, questions.

Comment: @Anthon sry about that. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preserve the order of the list sent as a param to build_tree I moved to a different angle. I use list instead and the order stays the same:

```
def build_tree(nodes, *args):
    # create empty tree to fill
    t = {}
    # First group all pages w/ same parent
    for node in nodes:
        if node.parentKey is None:
            key = 'root'
        else:
            key = node.parentKey.key()

        if not t.has_key(key):
            t[key] = []

        t[key].append({ 'page' : node, 'children' : []})

    pageTree = t['root']
    # Iterate over there
    build_page_tree(pageTree, t)

    return pageTree

def build_page_tree(pageTree, nodes):
    #Loop over selected list
    for parent, node in nodes.iteritems():
        # We don't need to loop over first level node
        if parent is not 'root':
            # Loop over current level in page tree
            for item in pageTree:
                # Match keys
                if item['page'].key() == parent:
                    # Save node as child
                    item['children'] = node
                    # Only need to loop over childs if they are present
                    build_page_tree(item['children'], nodes)
```